# how to change the parameter of the clone event

Tags: jquery

After clone the dropdown, I can change the id and name.  However, the parameter value  of the function is still using the original value. I searched the web and found the code at [Learn to Attach Event Handler with jQuery .change() Method](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/jquery-on-change). I may misunderstanding it, so it didn't change. Would you help me.

The original element: onchange='handleDrop('drp_0');

The clone element should be like that onchange='handleDrop('drp_1');

There is my code:

```
      var drop = firstRowClone.find('td:eq(1)').find('select');
      drop.attr('id', dropID);
      drop.attr('name', dropID);                       
      drop.change(dropID, 'handleDrop');
```

Answer (score 0):

drop.attr('onchange', 'handleDrop('' + dropID +'')');